# Error: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near **

Tags: java, mysql, sql, insert

I have an error message in Java eclipse. I have a database in MySql and it has colomns `String user_name`, `int id_time`, `int id_desk`, `int user_password`. I want to insert data with using

```
public void reserve(String user_name, int id_time, int id_desk, int user_password){

    try{
        String reserveSql = "INSERT INTO reservation"
                +"VALUES ('" + user_name + "," + id_time + "," + id_desk + "," + user_password + "');";
        stmt.executeUpdate(reserveSql);
    }catch (SQLException ex) {
        System.out.println("Error: " + ex.getMessage());
    }
}
```

method.

In database `user_name` is varchar(45), `id_time` is int(3), `id_desk` is int(3) and `user_password` is int(4)

But in main method when i write

```
object.reserve("irem",002,111,1111);
```

it give me error message that

> Error: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
>   corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
>   near ''irem,2,111,1111')' at line 1

how can i fix it? Thanks for helping

Comment: Learn to use parameterized queries.  or at some point you'll suffer from SQL injection.

Comment: And dont write integers with leading zero(es) unless you want them as octal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot spaces and " ' "- around the strings, but you have to "Learn to use parameterized queries" like xQbert says...

Comment: For parametrized queries, I recommend to read [the Java tutorial on the topic](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/prepared.html)